# startx нет ничего на экране

Tags: centos

Трабл в чем  при старте иксов появляется бекграунд рабочего стола и можно водить только мышой, никакого меню и прочего нет. с чем может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что ты там хотел увидеть?

startx запустил X'ы и все. Добавь в ~/.xinitrc оконный менеджер или ДЕ которое хочешь

Comment: Дык, как добавить то?

Comment: Дык, давай больше информации: - какой дистр? - какой ВМ/ДЕ хотишь использовать в конце концов?PS: ага дистр - centos, тогда - как был установлен (с графической оболочкой или нет)? Запускались когда-то иксы так как ты хочешь? почему такой костыльный метод старта иксов, почему не используеши gdm/kdm/xdm?PPS: если совсем влоб: сделай # echo exec 'то что хочешьзапустить' > ~/.xinitrc и юзай команду xinit)

Comment: centos 6  KDE хочу. был без графической установлен, скачивал и кде и гном. иксы не запускались только этот экран и все. дальше ничего.Можно ссылку если есть где глянуть, все пишут что просто качаешь кде гном и стартх и счастье, а тут нет счастья :)

Comment: Все решилось. неужели нужно было только в иниттаб прописать id:5 вместо 3 перезагрузиться и проблема решена?, но мне не нужно чтобы там всегда был оконный вариант загрузки.

Comment: Верни, как было, и для запуска юзай    # /etc/init.d/xdm startили как там в centos принято стартовать.

Comment: THX! :))))

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - слетела оболочка графическая. Зайдите через консоль восстановления и исправьте битые пакеты.

Comment: На новую систему ставилось. на которой не стояли иксы вообще.